# determine the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{s_n(a+1)}{ns_n(a)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If a is an arbitrary real number, let $s_n(a) =1^a+2^a+\cdots+n^a$.

Determine the following limit:

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{s_n(a+1)}{ns_n(a)}$
(Consider both positive and negative a as well as a=0)
Edit:

I could not treat this limit at all this is why i didnt write any attempts.I was not able to apply L'Hospital rule,and it is the first limit i tried to calculate a limit involving series,apart from geometric and telescoping series wich I was not able to use in this one.

Comment: Note that $s_{n} (a) /n^{a+1}\to 1/(a+1) $ if $a\neq - 1$. Dividing the numerator and denominator of the expression by $n^{a+2}$ we see that the limit is $\dfrac{a+1}{a+2}$ provided $a\neq - 1$ and $a\neq - 2$.

Comment: For $a=-1$ or $a=-2$ the result is easily  seen to be $0$.

Comment: Excuse me but can you explain $s_n(a)/n^{a+1}\to 1/(a+1)$

Comment: You can use Cesaro-Stolz Theorem to get that limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $a=-1$ then we have that $s_n(-1+1) =1^0+2^0+\cdots +n^0=n$.

yet $s_n(-1) = \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2} +\cdots+\frac{1}{n} = \ln n +\gamma$

the famous Harmonic number where $\gamma \approx 0.577$.

So $\lim \limits_{ n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n (\ln n+ \gamma)} = 0$.

the sum $1^a+2^a+3^a+\cdots+n^a$ is either always decreasing or always increasing, in both cases we can bound it be integrals.

so $s_n(a+1) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} k^{a+1}$ and $\frac{(n-1)^{a+2}-2^{a+2}}{a+2} =\int \limits_{2}^{n-1} k^{a+1} dk  \leq \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} k^{a+1}\leq \int \limits_{0}^{n+1} k^{a+1} dk =\frac{(n+1)^{a+2}}{a+2}$

and $s_n(a)  = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} k^a$ and $\frac{(n-1)^{a+1}-2^{a+1}}{a+1}=\int \limits_{2}^{n-1} k^a dk  \leq \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} k^a\leq \int \limits_{0}^{n+1} k^a dk =\frac{(n+1)^{a+1}}{a+1}$

so taking limits of lower bound from first sum with upper bound from second sum and vice-versa ,they must be equal to this to work,

by the above the limit is $0$ when $a+2<1$ meaning $a<-1$.

and when $a>-1$ the limit is $\frac{a+1}{a+2}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Can you explain further what limits should I take and why.Excuse my ignorrance.Thank you again!

Comment: Integrals are the better way, +1

Comment: You need one to maximize and once to minimize , so once you take the upper bound for one sum and lower bound for the other and once again but in reverse, and by squeeze theorem if they both have the same limits then so your original sum in the question since its bounded between them, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try with [Stolz-Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_n(a+1)}{ns_n(a)} =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1^{a+1}+2^{a+1}+\cdots+n^{a+1}}{n(1^a+2^a+\cdots+n^a)} =
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{a+1}}{(n+1)^{a+1} + (1^a+2^a+\cdots+n^a)}
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1^a+2^a+\cdots+n^a}{(n+1)^{a+1}}}
= \frac{1}{1 + \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1^a+2^a+\cdots+n^a}{(n+1)^{a+1}}}
= \cdots
$$
 and apply Stolz-Cesàro again.